# Why can you not sudo history?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, history, command-history

If I want to view root's bash history, why can I not just run `sudo history`? when I do it says command history not found, but if I run it without the sudo it runs fine.

Edit: it's a duplicate answer, but not a duplicate question to the one linked. The person asking either question will not know that it's a shell builtin command as opposed to a binary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't "sudo cd" work?](https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work)

Comment: That possible duplicate Q is essentially the answer - `history` is a bash shell builtin command. There may be other logs recording what sudo has been up to

Comment: lol it's a duplicate answer, but not a duplicate question. The person asking either question will not know that it's a shell builtin command as opposed to a binary.

Comment: That is true... reading my comment they'd know then ;-) Maybe I'll post an answer with how I checked a binary vs builtin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`history` is a bash shell builtin command, and `sudo` doesn't work with shell builtins.

---

## What's a builtin command and what's not?

I used the command **`which`** that *"returns  the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the environment"* to confirm that `history` was not an external (to bash) command.

For example, running

```
$ which history
$
```

returns nothing and the exit code is 1 (one or more specified commands is nonexistent or not executable) [FYI see the exit code with `echo $?`], while running

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$
```

and the exit code 0 (all specified commands are found and executable).

Also, in bash you can look up help for builtin commands with **`help`** (or searching the `man bash` page). For example, typing

```
$ help history
history: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or history -ps
arg [arg...]
   Display or manipulate the history list.
...
```

shows bash's help info. Running `help non-bash-command` returns something similar to this:

```
$ help ls
bash: help: no help topics match `ls'.  Try `help help' or `man -k ls' or
`info ls'.
```

and the exit code 1

---

## So what has sudo been doing?

You can search your own history for `sudo` commands your user has run (and not skipped saving it to history) with `grep '^sudo' .bash_history` or `history|less` or similar.

Or, on Ubuntu the file `/var/log/auth.log` keeps records of what `sudo` has been doing for all users, search for "sudo" in there (other distros may use the file `/var/log/secure`), or could use

```
sudo grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

or run `sudo journalctl _COMM=sudo` if you've got systemd.

See the question ["Details about sudo commands executed by all user" on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167935/details-about-sudo-commands-executed-by-all-user) for more details

Answer (score 4):

`history` is a bash builtin, not a regular command; `sudo` doesn't start a shell to execute the command you give it, it just tries to execute it directly (as a regular command), so it's not available.

You can use `sudo bash` to open a root shell command and then run `history`, but if you want a one-liner, well it's a little complicated. bash only enables its history mechanism when it's run in interactive mode, and if you do something like `sudo bash -c history` (the `-c` tells bash "here's the command I want you to execute:"), it treats it as non-interactive mode and doesn't actually display any history. Even adding `-i` (for interactive mode) didn't work when I tested it. But this did:

```
sudo bash -i <<<history
```

Note that `<<<` is a bash-only feature; in other shells you might have to use `echo history | sudo bash -i` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What about just logging in as sudo temporary and then execute *history*?
First

```
sudo -s
```

and then

```
history
```