# Run "cd" command as superuser in Linux

Tags: linux, sudo, cd, working-directory

Is there a way to run the `cd` command with superuser privileges to gain access to directories that are owned by root? When I run `sudo cd <path>`, I get `sudo: cd: command not found`.

Comment: You can run only external commands with `sudo`, so you need to invoke `bash` to perform the `cd` command, using `sudo bash -c cd ...`.

Comment: I know, that's what I read on this superuser post https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work.

Comment: My question is how can I use the ```cd``` command with superuser privileges, since sudo doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question: I was thinking of the `mkdir` command. Silly mistake.

Comment: FWIW POSIX says that cd ought to be available as an external command. [Questionable value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058) Sure, but that's the spec.

Comment: The easy way is to log in as root, assuming you're typing the cd command directly, rather than in a macro. (You don't say exactly how you're using it.)

Comment: You can become root with `sudo -i`.

Comment: Assume you could do `sudo cd /foo/bar`. It might happen that after that you cannot even `cd ..`

Comment: If you want to play around with the situation you can change as a normal user in a directory and after that use a different root shell to remove the x permission. (A variation of this is chroot with forgetting to cd first)

Comment: Just about everybody learning to use the CLI (command line interface) makes this mistake sooner or later. It's a natural thing to want to do from a human perspective, but it doesn't make any sense from the shell's perspective.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The other answer isn't wrong.

Possibly a better answer is:

The sudo tool is intended to take actions as a superuser, and you're describing something that is more of a state change that would precede actions such as 'ls' or 'vi' or others to make them simpler.

I suggest, e.g. if you wanted to edit a file in /root/private/:

```
sudo ls /root
sudo ls /root/private
sudoedit /root/private/<name from previous ls command>
```

This is definitely more typing, and a little harder than just changing directories.  However, it is *far* more audit-able, and much more in-line with the principles behind sudo than running some variant of 'sudo bash.'

If you are working in a secure environment, your IA team will thank you.  If you find yourself wondering: "What change did I make the other day?," then *you* will  thank you, because you won't have to wonder what file or files you edited.

All of this said, enabling and executing some form of 'sudo bash' is definitely easier.  If you were looking for easier, why are you using 'sudo' in the first place instead of just logging in as root?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about relying on each admin's .bash_history instead of using something more reliable like etckeeper?

Comment: The hideously annoying thing in this is that tab-completion of the filename in the last command doesn't work if the non-root user doesn't have read access to the directory. So you have to copy paste or hand-type. I wonder if anyone would have created a `sudo`-using completion script for Bash.

Comment: @ilkkachu: At that point I usually just `sudo -s` to start a root shell on personal-use systems (so auditing isn't a huge deal).  I don't want automatically-generated commands running under sudo.  (Cluttering logs at best, at worst exposing some hackily-written completion code to malicious filenames with spaces and worse in them.)

Comment: @grawity: I was referring to the system security logs, where sudo typically logs commands issued, including time, user, current working directory, etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yep. I'd be tempted to just `chmod +r` or raise the question if a custom should be made where some `staff` group has read permissions to root owned directories, because tab-completion is _useful_. Yes, the completion code would need to be carefully written (and I think I've seen some not work with funny filenames), but I don't think the clutter should be an issue since you can just `grep` out any `ls` commands which don't do anything, and which people will need to run under `sudo` anyway if they don't have read permissions as their regular UID.

Comment: An alias for `sudoedit` is `sudo -e`, it saves 1 keypress

Comment: @ferrybig: Fair point, but it means I move my fingers two rows below, and two rows above home row, whereas 'edit' (not to mention 'sudoedit') is a word that I touch-type without thinking.  I might save one keypress and increase time and typos significantly.

Comment: I don't have the folder `/root/private` so what do I do?

Answer (score 25):

As you noted, `cd` is a shell built-in command, and **there's a reason** for that: the "current directory" is a per-process parameter which can be only changed by the process *itself*.

Your shell's working directory cannot be changed by any child process – so even if you manage to run `cd` in a privileged subshell, it'll only change the working directory of that temporary subshell, and it does not matter what method of raising privileges you use.

So for `sudo cd` to work, sudo itself would have to be a shell built-in, and it would need some way to raise privileges of an already-running process. Currently no such mechanism exists on Linux (nor most other operating systems).

---

One way to achieve what you want is to run an *interactive* shell with root privileges (any method works), and just use the regular `cd` in it:

```
[user@host /]$ sudo bash
[root@host /]# cd /root/secret
```

If you want to do it all in one command, it would have to look like this – first change the working directory, then start an interactive shell:

```
sudo bash -c "cd /root/secret && bash"
```

```
su -c "cd /root/secret && zsh"
```

Note: The outer command doesn't have to be a shell, it just needs to be *something* that changes its working directory and executes a new command. Recent Linux systems have one or two helpers which could be used:

```
sudo nsenter --wd="/root/secret" bash       # util-linux v2.23 (debian jessie)
```

```
sudo env --chdir="/root/secret" bash        # coreutils v8.28 (debian buster)
```

The advantage of this method is that it doesn't require nested quoting; you can run a multi-word command without having troubles with whitespace or special characters.

Finally, some programs have a built-in option to change their working directory:

```
sudo make -C /etc
```

```
sudo git -C /root/secret log
```

Comment: `sudo -s` starts an interactive `$SHELL` in the current directory; it's (AFAIK) the canonical way to do `sudo bash`

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do what I needed to do was this:

```
sudo -s
```

As described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/241137/1120251).